# use pyspark foreachpartition but retain partition specific variables

Tags: apache-spark, partition

I have a requirement where each spark worker retains its variables between iterations. The variable is a structure too large to include in every RDD. I can use foreachpartition, but there is no mechanism for passing some variable once per partition (and pass it back afterwards). There is no continuity between calls to a partition even with the same id. repeated broadcasting is too expensive. Does any one know of a way to get around this?

Comment: would Apache Ignite be an answer to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send in an array of these variables and use the partition_id to access the values for continuity.